# why is there a difference if I add a class to a span tag as opposed to a div tag?

Tags: html, css

When I use a css class within a div tag it seems to ignore what is inside the css.

```
.centered {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
}
```

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="centered">
    I am centered with bg around me
</div>
```

When is use the same class with a `span` tag nested within the `div` element it does what I want.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="centered">I am centered with bg around me</span>
</div>
```

Why is this? What makes the difference?

[This is with the first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Amyx.png)
[This is with the second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odP3M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div />` is a block level element, which takes up 100 % of the available width by default. `<span />` is an inline element, which only takes up the minimum amount of width it needs to display its content.

There's a [really good article on learnlayout.com](http://learnlayout.com/display.html) that does a great job explaining this.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer!

Answer (score 0):

Its because a span is a inline element and a div is a block element.

To see the difference you can make the span a block element by doing this:

```
.centered {
  display: block
}
```

[More about inline vs block](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering it was useful!